# get values from js to aem sightly component. In JS values are stored in the form of array of arrays

Tags: javascript, aem, aem-6

How do we get values from array of arrays to cq5 component.

In the java script I am getting the values from dialog. While returning them as an object (This object is array of arrays like for example : [{},{},{},{}] ). When this object is returned to AEM 6.2 component (Sightly component), these has to be printed on the page. How can this be achieved.?

Answer (score -1):

You have to POST the data back to the resource the values are originated from to get a full roundtrip. This will probably not work on the publishers, as these are shielded by the dispatcher.